# JAXB - Binding element to Set instead of List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there a way to make JAXB generate the Collection Set instead of List for an defined element?

For example generating a Set of books for this xsd:

```
<xs:element name="Collection">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name ="books">
       <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="book" type="bookType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
```

When using the following bindings.xml

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Shop']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='books']">
        <jxb:property collectionType="java.util.HashSet" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

A List of books with a concret HashSet implementation is generated:

```
List<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with a custom binding, because according to the guide on [Customizing JAXB Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html):

> `collectionType` defines the
>   customization value
>   `propertyCollectionType`, which is the
>   collection type for the property.
>   `propertyCollectionType` if specified,
>   can be either indexed or any
>   fully-qualified class name that
>   implements `java.util.List`.

However, it might be possible to do this if you wrote your own **xjc plugin**. Take a look at the following article to see how: [Writing a plug-in for the JAXB RI is really easy](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html)